# Прокручиваемый список в windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ui

Привет! Пишу приложение под wp7, очень нравится прокручиваемый список как в будильнике когда выбираем цифры. Подскажите как называется этот элемент?

Comment: Не находил много интересных элементов UI, так как не знал про Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте. Если не ошибаюсь `TimePicker` и `DatePicker`. Вот пару статей по их использованию

1. [DatePicker and TimePicker](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=172)
2. [TimePicker](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/windowsphone/controls/timepicker.php) - очень много полезных примеров для работы с элементами интерфейса, на русском языке.

Comment: О, спасибо! То что нужно!